# How to make dependent dropdown list from Google Sheet?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google sheet with custom HTML form. The form contains two `<select>` elements.

```html
<div class="input-group mb-3">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <label class="input-group-text" for="category_name">Категория</label>
        </div>
        <select class="custom-select" id="category_name" name="category_name" required>
          <option value="" selected></option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <label class="input-group-text" for="contragent_name">Контрагент</label>
        </div>
        <select class="custom-select" id="contragent_name" name="contragent_name">
          <option value="" selected></option>
        </select>
      </div>
```

I want to get dependent dropdown list at the second selection (`contragent_name`).
Just two lists:

- first: if selected value of `category_name` is not equal to `'Заработная Плата'` --> `contragent_name` selection list must be populated with `getContragent()` (just values of one column)
- second: if selected value of `category_name` is equal to `'Заработная Плата'` --> `contragent_name` selection list must be populated with `getStaffList()` (just array with names) with `required` attribute.

I tried to write script but it does not work

```html
<script>
      (function () {
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(
          function (selectList) {
            var select = document.getElementById("category_name");
            for( var i=0; i<selectList.length; i++ ) {
              var option = document.createElement("option");
              option.value = selectList[i][0];
              option.text = selectList[i][0];
              select.add(option);
            }
          }
        ).getCategory();
      }());
      
      $(function() {
        $('#category_name').on("change", function () {
          if ($(this).val() !== 'Заработная Плата') {
          function () {
            google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(
            function (selectList) {
              var select = document.getElementById("contragent_name");
              for( var i=0; i<selectList.length; i++ ) {
                var option = document.createElement("option");
                option.value = selectList[i][0];
                option.text = selectList[i][0];
                select.add(option);
                }
              }
              ).getContragent();
          }()} else {
           function () {
            google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(
            function (selectList) {
              var select = document.getElementById("contragent_name");
              select.required = true;
              for( var i=0; i<selectList.length; i++ ) {
                var option = document.createElement("option");
                option.value = selectList[i];
                option.text = selectList[i];
                select.add(option);
                }
              }
              ).getStuffList();
          }()}
        });      
      });    
    </script>
```

Where I'm wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Dependent Dropdown</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label for="category">Category</label>
        <select id="category" class="form-control" required>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label for="items">Items</label>
        <select id="items" class="form-control" required>
        </select>
      </div>      
    </form>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

JS

```
var db = [["Vegetable","Carrot"],["Vegetable","Onion"],["Fruit","Apple"],["Fruit","Banana"]];

$(document).ready(function(){
  var categoryLists = db.map(x => x[0]);
  categoryLists = [... new Set(categoryLists)]; //get unique category values
  categoryLists.forEach(x => $("#category").append(new Option(x, x))); //new Option("text", "value")
  $("#category").on("change",updateItemLists).change(); //add event listner and trigger it once to show items
});

function updateItemLists(){
  var category = $("option:selected", this).text(); //get category
  var itemLists = db.filter(x => x[0] == category).map(x =>x[1]);
  $("#items option").remove();
  itemLists.forEach( (x, i) => $("#items").append(new Option(x,i))); //x: array value ; i: array index
};
```